# Conditional Formatting using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I am working with a pandas dataframe. In this dataframe I have two columns one is enrollment (e_gk) and the other one is attendence (a_gk), there are some errors in data where attendence is high than actual enrollment. I want to replace the values of attendence with actual enrollment in such errors.

My main code line for this condition. Here in iterations 'e' is for enrollment and 'a' for attendence.

```
df['a_gk'] = [e if a > e else a for a, e in df.a_gk and df.e_gk]
```

this gives me the following error:

> "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `and` operator doesn't support Series operation in `df.a_gk and df.e_gk`. You may want `zip` two columns together.

```py
df['a_gk'] = [e if a > e else a for a, e in zip(df.a_gk, df.e_gk)]
```

But you could also use `apply` on rows.

```py
df['a_gk'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['e_gk'] if row['a_gk'] > row['e_gk'] else row['e_gk'], axis=1)
```

Or with `np.where`

```py
df['a_gk'] = np.where(df['a_gk'] > df['e_gk'], df['e_gk'], df['a_gk'])
```